# How to handle back button click in React Project?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

We are using **React** with **React Router**.
Changing routes from projects to users and then clicking back button to go to projects works perfectly, but if I'm in project page and search "project 1", the Query param will change ( Not the route ) and then if I click back only the URL is changed but the page is not refreshed according to query parameters.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
<Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
```

So now in Projects I have a search, as soon as I add text in the search box and Hit enter the URL will be **/projects/?searchString=hello**
Then if I search **again** it will be **/?searchString=again**
So now If I click the back button, the URL will change to **/projects/?searchString=hello** but the Page is not refreshed or anything.

Comment: Please share you route file

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: Can you include all applicable code to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? In this case, the **router** (*not routes*) JSX and the `Projects` component.

Comment: How are you updating the URL?

Comment: @KartikBhalala are you using React hook or class components ?